# When does a job posting expire on careers.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, jobs

Is there any particular expiry period for jobs on [careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) or does the poster specify it, after which the expired job link throws up a *404 Page Not Found*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ## How much do Job Listings cost?
>
> Pricing starts at $350 **for a 30-day listing**, or less if you
>   pre-purchase multiple jobs.

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/about-listings

You can extend your listing for another 30 days (if memory serves correctly) if you wish.